# MongoDB map reduce producing strange result

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am implementing a simple 'get max value' map reduce in MongoDB (c# driver).
For my tests I have 10 items in a collection with int _id = 1 to 10.

My map and reduce are as follows:

```
var map = "function() {emit('_id', this.Id);}";
var reduce = "function(key, values) {var max = 1; for (id in values) {if(id>max) {max=id;}} } return max;}";
```

When I run however I get the result 9, strange!!

I think that the map is outputting a string, and thus the compare is not working as desired.
Any help would be great

Comment: Can you make sure that your data (the Id field) is in fact a number and not a string?

Comment: really looks like a comparing between strings, not numbers.

Comment: Are all your ids unique? Reduce function won't run because it expects an array in the values, whereas when there is only one item for a key, reduce function just does not run. So I suspect you have more than one items with id 9.

Comment: _id is an int. I have checked in the mongo shell and the _id =10 is defined as "_id" :10

Comment: Yes all the id's are unique. At the moment I only have 10 elements in the DB so its quite easy to check

Comment: If all the ids are unique and your key in the map is only that id, reduce phase won't work because of a design issue. Check the jira https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5818 If you are just trying to get familiar with map reduce I would suggest to try different scenarios where using map-reduce really makes sense.

Comment: Thanks cubbuk. Yes I'm trying to get a list of all the different scenarios which I can use Map Reduce with. I understand now, it would be dumb to use this scenario in practice. Whats crazy is that there are a lot of examples online doing just this. Please post your comment as an answer, it was really useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce function won't run if the values contain only one item. If all the ids are unique and your key in the map is only that id, reduce phase won't work because of a design issue (for improving performance). If you need to change the format of your reduce output, you should use `finalize` method. Or just take a look at the `aggregation framework` which provides quite useful tools for playing with data.

Check the jira

> jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5818

If you are just trying to get familiar with map reduce I would suggest to try different scenarios where using map-reduce really makes sense

Cheers